# Multipule Query Strings .htaccess Redirect

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

Im a bit stuck where I need to redirect 80+ URLs' which have

```
 content.php?111-rest-of-url 

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?64-random-url-here-again$
 RewriteRule ^content.php$ https://www.newdomain.com/random-url-here-again/? [R=301,L,QSD]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?61-random-url-here$
 RewriteRule ^content.php$ https://www.newdomain.com/random-url-here/? [R=301,L,QSD]
```

And there are around another 80 url's written out like this.  However, when testing on site, no matter what URL you try...it always returns the first one in the .htaccess

From what I have been reading am I correct in assuming you can only use one query string of this kind ? if so is there away around this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to accomplish what I need by doing the following, hopefully it will help someone else.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/content\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^196-random-url-here-again$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/random-url-here-again/? [R=301,L,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/content\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^196-random-url-here$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/random-url-here/? [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Not sure what the difference is but it works :),  would be grateful  to hear from someone to explain the difference in what I have done so I understand it in the future.